# Getting "invalid list filter" when filtering GCP Workflows using Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-workflows

I have a process where I need to list off failed workflows in Google cloud platform so they can be highlighted to be fixed. I have managed to do this quite simply writing a gcloud command and calling it in a shell script, but I need to transfer this to Python.

I have the following shell command as an example where I am able to filter on a specific workflow to pull back any failures using the `--filter` flag.

```
gcloud workflows executions list --project test-project "projects/test-project/locations/europe-west4/workflows/test-workflow"  --location europe-west4 --filter STATE:FAILED
```

In the documentation for filtering it not possible to do this on the executions but on the list workflows instead, which is fine. You can see within the code snippet below I am trying to filter on `STATE:FAILED` like in the gcloud command.

The example below doesn't work and there are no examples within the Google cloud documents. I have checked in the following webpage:

https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/workflows/latest/google.cloud.workflows_v1.types.ListWorkflowsRequest

```
from google.cloud import workflows_v1
from google.cloud.workflows import executions_v1

# Create a client
workflow_client = workflows_v1.WorkflowsClient()
execution_client = executions_v1.ExecutionsClient()
project = "test-project"
location = "europe-west4"
# Initialize request argument(s)
request = workflows_v1.ListWorkflowsRequest(
    parent=f"projects/{project}/locations/{location}",
    filter="STATE:FAILED"
)
# Make the request
workflow_page_result = workflow_client.list_workflows(request=request)
# Handle the response
with open("./workflows.txt", "w") as workflow_file:
    for workflow_response in workflow_page_result:
        name = workflow_response.name
        request = executions_v1.ListExecutionsRequest(
            parent=name,
        )
        execution_page_result = execution_client.list_executions(request=request)
        # Handle the response
        for execution_response in execution_page_result:
            print(execution_response)
        workflow_file.write(name)
```

What is the correct syntax for filtering on the failed state within the Python code? Where would I look to find this information in the Google documentation?

I get the following error message:

```
/Users/richard.drury/code/gcp/git/service-level-monitoring/venv/bin/python /Users/richard.drury/code/gcp/git/service-level-monitoring/daily_checks/sensor_checks/workflows.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/richard.drury/code/gcp/git/service-level-monitoring/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 50, in error_remapped_callable
    return callable_(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/richard.drury/code/gcp/git/service-level-monitoring/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 946, in __call__
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
  File "/Users/richard.drury/code/gcp/git/service-level-monitoring/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 849, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _InactiveRpcError(state)
grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT
    details = "The request was invalid: invalid list filter: Field 'STATE' not found in 'resource'."
    debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1670416298.880340000","description":"Error received from peer ipv4:216.58.213.10:443","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":967,"grpc_message":"The request was invalid: invalid list filter: Field 'STATE' not found in 'resource'.","grpc_status":3}"
>

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/richard.drury/code/gcp/git/service-level-monitoring/daily_checks/sensor_checks/workflows.py", line 15, in <module>
    workflow_page_result = workflow_client.list_workflows(request=request)
  File "/Users/richard.drury/code/gcp/git/service-level-monitoring/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/workflows_v1/services/workflows/client.py", line 537, in list_workflows
    response = rpc(
  File "/Users/richard.drury/code/gcp/git/service-level-monitoring/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/method.py", line 154, in __call__
    return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/richard.drury/code/gcp/git/service-level-monitoring/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 52, in error_remapped_callable
    raise exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc) from exc
google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument: 400 The request was invalid: invalid list filter: Field 'STATE' not found in 'resource'. [field_violations {
  field: "filter"
  description: "invalid list filter: Field \'STATE\' not found in \'resource\'."
}
]

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Did u solve it? Struggling here with the same question

Comment: @p.magalhaes i'm afraid not. I found it bizzare how I couldn't use filter like the CLI. I think I ended up retreiving a full list and he using python to filter.

Answer (score 0):

In a YAML Workflow using the [Workflows Executions API](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/reference/executions/rest/v1/projects.locations.workflows.executions/list#query-parameters) and after a lot of trial and error testing different filter values (because I could not find examples in the documentation) I was able to get a list of active executions using this workflow step:

```yaml
      - getActiveExecutions:
          call: http.get
          args:
            auth:
              type: OAuth2
            url: ${"https://workflowexecutions.googleapis.com/v1/projects/" + sys.get_env("GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT_ID") + "/locations/" + sys.get_env("GOOGLE_CLOUD_LOCATION") + "/workflows/" + sys.get_env("GOOGLE_CLOUD_WORKFLOW_ID") + "/executions"}
            query:
                filter: state="ACTIVE"
          result: activeExecutions
```

This may work in your python example, but you may need to use the filter value like below because the quotes around [the state value](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/reference/executions/rest/v1/projects.locations.workflows.executions#state) were important:

```py
request = workflows_v1.ListWorkflowsRequest(
    parent=f"projects/{project}/locations/{location}",
    filter='state="FAILED"'
)
```